# Where are functions and variables exported in Node.js module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js

One technique to solve cyclical references issues between modules in `Node.js` is to export an object before requiring other modules.

For example:

```
var MyModule = {};
module.exports = MyModule;

var req1 = require("req1.js");
var req2 = require("req2.js");
...

module.exports.MyFunction = function(...) { ... };
module.exports.MyVariable = 22;
...
```

Where are `MyFunction` and `MyVariable` stored? Is it in the `MyModule` object?

The reason I am asking this question is I want to know whether I can simplify my code. Could I safely replace my code with the following?

```
var MyModule = {};
module.exports = MyModule;

var req1 = require("req1.js");
var req2 = require("req2.js");
...

MyModule.MyFunction = function(...) { ... };
MyModule.MyVariable = 22;
...
```

Comment: Why not simply give it a try? It's only 10 lines of code. http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those two code snippets are functionally equivalent.